# How to merge two multi-dimensional arrays and update duplicates?

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to use "array_merge($a,$b)" but this does not work for what I'm doing. Here are two arrays :

```
$a =
Array
(
    [Mike] => Array
        (
            [100] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

            [200] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

            [300] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

            [400] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

        )

)


$b =
Array
(
    [Mike] => Array
        (
            [500] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

            [600] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

The concept is a user "Mike" adds items to their list (100,200,300,400). This list is saved in the database. Mike logs out and starts a new list a few days later as a anonymous guest, adding items (500,600) saved in his session. When he is finished and logs back in, I want to combine the two lists and save the updated list. If I use "array_merge" and since the array key is [Mike], by design it completely replaces $a with $b rather than merging the item numbers together.

How can I combine this? Also if two items are the same in both lists, such as (100,200,300,400) in one list and (100,500) in the second list (item number "100" being the duplicate here). I would like the [quantity] and [attribute] fields of the "100" in the second list to overwrite the those fields for item "100" in the first list.

Thanks
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code. Just be sure to put your latest result first. It will give you the result you want.

```
  $c = $b['Mike']+$a['Mike'];
```

thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was actually: $c['Mike'] = $b['Mike'] + $a['Mike'] in order to keep the array structure the same. (please ignore my previous comment about a secondary question, I was able to solve it with foreach loops on both arrays.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_replace_recursive` function(*"to update duplicates"*):

```
$result = array_replace_recursive($a, $b);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [Mike] => Array
        (
            [100] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

            [200] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

            [300] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

            [400] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

            [500] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )

            [600] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [attribute] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php

Comment: Unfortunately this causes a problem, it sort of combines the two arrays, but the item numbers are reset for the second array. (500,600) get reset to (4,5) after the merge.

Comment: that's not true. I've tested and added the output. Or, maybe, you have different key types among those two arrays. Make sure that both arrays are indexed with numbers